# Run a Query After Completion of Multiple asynchronous Queries

Tags: mongodb, java-8, vert.x

I am using vertx mongoclient with this code:

```
mongoClient.getCollections(res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            if (res.result().size() > 0) {
                for (String collection : res.result()) {
                    mongoClient.dropCollection(collection, resDrop -> {
                        if (resDrop.succeeded()) {
                            LOGGER.warn(collection + "was dropped");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else LOGGER.warn("database was dropped");
        } else LOGGER.warn("database was dropped");
    });
```

I want to create some new Collections After all old Collections have been Dropped
But as we know , dropping collections executed asynchronously 
How can i figure out when all of old collections have been dropped ?

Comment: Why dont you destroy all collections in single command? Check this http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java/#_running_other_mongodb_commands

Comment: This is just for test 
i need this for Run a Query After Completion of Multiple asynchronous Queries

Comment: Use completablefuture or rxjava

Comment: Use the `CountdownLatch` with a num of your collections to delete. .countDown() on collection drop success then use .awat() it awaits when all of the operations are performed then execute your stuff. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mongoClient.getCollections(res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            if (res.result().size() > 0) {
                **List<Future> futureList  = new ArrayList<>();** 
                for (String collection : res.result()) {
                    mongoClient.dropCollection(collection, resDrop -> {
                        if (resDrop.succeeded()) {
                            **Future future = Future.future();
                            futureList.add(future);
                            future.complete();**
                            LOGGER.warn(collection + "was dropped");
                        }else{
                          future.fail(ar.cause());  
                       }

                    });
                }

               **CompositeFuture.all(futureList).setHandler(ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                        LOGGER.info("All collections was dropped");
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.warn("One or all collections was not dropped");
                    }
                });**
            } else LOGGER.warn("database was dropped");
        } else LOGGER.warn("database was dropped");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common [asynchronous coordination](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_async_coordination) issue. Have a look at the [Concurrent composition](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_concurrent_composition) section in the Vert.x documentation.

Comment: [Concurrent composition works with a list of futures](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/CompositeFuture.html#all-java.util.List-) as well

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [CompletableFutures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). You can call the [allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) method.